# Story wherein special glass slows time

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I don't recall much about this at all.

A friend, who had recommended many other books/authors I ended up liking, told me about a story in which a scientist develops some kind of special glass, that had some property like slowing down light by a factor of a trillion, or something else odd like that, adventure ensuing.

He's since moved away, and now I'm wondering what this book might have been.

Comment: Perhaps Bob Shaw's slow glass? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Shaw . Do you remember anything about the age of the book?

Comment: @Tony Meyer - well, since most of the other things this guy recommended were 1950's-1970's, I'd hazard to guess somewhere in that time frame.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly [Bob Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Shaw)'s [*Slow Glass* stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?25395) (1966), starting with [“Light of Other Days”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41206) and collected in *Other Days, Other Eyes*.

Comment: yep. now I see the blurb on the other side of @Tony Meyer's link, I am sure of it. I misremembered, of course. It wasn't just that light takes a million years to get through, it was that you could make windows into the past.