# Old story about slow light

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this story before I was in high school, so it must have been written before 1972. It was about a house having windows made of a special kind of glass with such a high index of refraction that it took on the order of a century for light to pass through it. Visitors to the house "witness" a murder that took place many years ago by looking in or out the windows. That's all I can remember, but I was struck by the idea and would like to track down the exact reference. The title or text may have contained a reference to "slow light".

Comment: What a fantastic story idea.  I'm going to buy the book.

Comment: Terry Pratchett's discworld also famously features slow light. However, it's faster than in the story you are looking for.

Answer (score 38):

It could be [**Light of Other Days** by **Bob Shaw**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_of_Other_Days) (1966)

Plot

> The narrator is touring northwest Scotland with his wife Selina. Their
> relationship is in trouble, and news of her pregnancy has made it
> worse. Their holiday, intended to improve the situation, has not been
> a success. Travelling through a remote area, they find a place that
> sells panes of slow glass. **This is glass that light takes a long time
> to pass through, even years, so that a pane of this glass shows a
> scene from the past**. People buy slow glass that has been placed in
> picturesque scenery so that later they can enjoy the view in their
> homes or workplaces. The best quality slow glass is priced by its
> "thickness", corresponding to the number of years of scenic view
> contained within it. The narrator thinks that an extravagant idea like
> buying slow glass might set right his relationship with Selina.
>
> Leaving the car, they walk along a path, where they see panes of slow
> glass facing a view of a loch. They meet Mr Hagan, who is sitting on a
> low wall in front of his stone farmhouse and looking towards the
> house. Inside, through the window, they see a young woman, presumably
> Mrs Hagan, and a small boy. Hagan fetches a rug from the house so that
> Selina can sit on a wall. The narrator, sensing that Mrs Hagan,
> looking towards them from inside, is not aware of them, wonders if she
> is blind; Selina remarks that her dress is out of fashion.
>
> The narrator discusses with Hagan the price of his slow glass. Hagan
> says how fine the view is from there; as he talks, the narrator, still
> looking at the house, wonders if the small boy is blind as well.
> Eventually, although Selina is not impressed, the narrator decides to
> buy. While Hagan is fetching the glass, rain begins, so Selina goes to
> the house to return the rug. When the door is opened, the interior is
> seen to be disordered and squalid; Hagan is living alone. The family
> scene of wife and child was of years ago, seen through slow glass. As
> the couple leaves with their purchase, **Hagan sorrowfully tells them
> his wife and child were killed in a road accident six years
> previously**.
>
> The narrator, walking with his wife back along the path, feels their
> relationship is somehow strengthened. He looks back at Hagan, who is
> sitting at his usual place, looking towards the house.

[Full story](https://gebseng.com/media_archeology/reading_materials/Bob_Shaw-Light_of_Other_Days.pdf)

Comment: It's been asked about a few times here. Here's one of them https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258445/novel-with-replaceable-eyes-that-store-memory

Comment: @OrganicMarble seems that TS asked for a story, and "Other days, other eyes" is a novel, based on this story.

Comment: Other Days, Other Eyes is actually a fix-up consisting of all the slow glass stories and other material. Chapter 2 is "Light of Other Days".

Answer (score 22):

It’s definitely one of Bob Shaw”s “slow glass” stories and I suspect the specific story you’re after is “Burden of Proof” (first published in *Analog* in May 1967), but I don’t have any sources to hand with which to verify that.

Comment: It could well be: 
"Ever since slow glass appeared in several fashionable stores, people have wondered: what would happen if a crime was committed in front of it?"
See full text: https://koapp-narod-ru.translate.goog/hudlit/sfiction/book566.htm?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: "Burden of Proof" is about a judge waiting for confirmation of a verdict by something that finally shows up in a slow glass window. It's in *Other Days, Other Eyes* chapter 4.